# Counting matrix elements of a symmetric tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, tensors

Does someone know how to count the number of independent elements of a symmetric or antisymmetric tensor of order n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every symmetric order $k$ tensor can be written uniquely as a linear combination of $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ basis tensors (from an $n$-dimensional vector space).

The coefficients of this set of linear combinations are what you refer to as independent elements.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Guilhem